# How to Serialize object with XFile in Hydrated Bloc?

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I'm using `image_picker` plugin to get images from gallery.

I save that image(XFile) in an object with bunch of properties. My State of HydratedBloc has list of that object. What is the best way to store that XFile for HydratedBloc?

What is the best way to write `toJson` and `fromJson` functions for `Expense` class.
I have two thoughts

1. I can convert `XFile` object to `base64` and then convert it back again in `fromJson`.
2. I can write `Xfile` to `ApplicationDocumentsDirectory` as a File and then get it back from there to tmp storage on `fromJson`.

At second option, I have to delete permanent file from `ApplicationDocumentsDirectory` when I get back the file to tmp storage to avoid bloating storage of phone.

Codes are like below.
My Object Expense

```
class Expense extends Equatable {
  final String companyName;
  final DateTime? date;
  final XFile? image;

  ...
  ...
}
```

ExpenseState

```
class ExpenseState extends Equatable {
  final List<Expense> expenses;

  const ExpenseState({required this.expenses});

  ...
}
```

ExpenseBloc

```
class ExpenseBloc extends HydratedBloc<ExpenseEvent, ExpenseState> {

   @override
  ExpenseState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ExpenseState.fromJson(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(ExpenseState state) {
    return state.toJson();
  }

}
```